# Training loss started extremely lower than validation loss. What is happening?

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

My training loss started very low at 0.0181 whereas validation loss started at 2.4625, which is over 150 fold difference. Validation loss did improve as the model tries to learn and memorize generalizable features, yet it never gets to the level of the training loss and the training loss becomes extremely small as the model learns more epochs.

The model is trained on ~31K data instances (train+val) for a binary classification problem. The model adopts a Conv1D layer fed into Bidirectional GRU units, which is then output into two fully connected layers.

Total params: 294,737
Trainable params: 294,417
Non-trainable params: 320

Model architecture (figure): [Model architecture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VgKs6.png)

```
Training model....
(31639, 121, 4)
Epoch 1/100
learning rate: 0.01
15/15 [==============================] - 6s 190ms/step - loss: 0.0181 - accuracy: 0.0926 - val_loss: 2.4625 - val_accuracy: 0.0506
Epoch 2/100
learning rate: 0.01
15/15 [==============================] - 2s 148ms/step - loss: 0.0104 - accuracy: 0.0478 - val_loss: 2.1587 - val_accuracy: 0.0506
.....
```

Full model loss training history [Model Loss](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CoYvJ.png)

---

I trained it for 100 epochs with several callback modifications, and binary cross-entropy was used as the loss function. The dataset was highly imbalanced with 5% positive labels and 95% negative labels.

```
model = Model(inputs=[f_input, rc_input], outputs=predict)
adam=Adam(lr=hyperparam_dict['initial_lr'],beta_1=0.9, beta_2=0.999, epsilon=1e-08)
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer=adam, metrics=['accuracy'])
```

Loss history see here (figure):
[Model training/val loss vs epochs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7KbPS.png)

Accuracy history see here (figure):
[Model training/val accuracy vs epochs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ywr9g.png)

Comment: it means you are overfitting. in other words your model is too complex and your task is too simple. you can try to draw graphs using history of the model. so draw validation error and training error graph. if the gap is too high build a simpler model.

Comment: Can you show the train loss during the 1st (or any) epoch?

Comment: I apologize that this is my first time posting questions. I hope I have done it correctly. I have attached accuracy and training history plots as figures in the description text, as well as first two epochs of trainin loss, validation loss, and accuracies, etc. Training loss of first epochs is 0.0181.

Comment: Please show the loss *during* the 1st epoch. not just the single value of the epoch end.